# RSVP to FB events from websites.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to RSVP to an fb event from a website. I have integrated the facebook events through the graph api on a website. Now I want to add Join maybe and Invite buttons on the website. User will have to login on his account when he press the join button and that's it.

I've gone through the graph api documentation. But what I've understood from that is I can access the data of fields like who's attending and who has declined. Is it possible to Join or decline events from a website?

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried?

RSVP'ing is possible through the API as per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/attending#publish):

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{event-id}/attending'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Check the other [edges](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#edges) and see which ones you can publish against (e.g. `declined`).

Moreover, make sure to double check the [requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-rsvp_event) for the `rsvp_event` permission.